# Looping for array lists and adding values which match two array lists into a new one

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make a program that matches a clients interests with aspects of a holiday, I have an array list of holidays and an array list of strings for the clients interests and I wanted to create a new array list which would add all elements that are contained in both. This is what I have but it comes up with a null pointer exception, Any ideas where I've gone wrong?
the debugger points towards the disjoint and at " int c1size = c1.size();"
Relevant parts of code...

In main...

```
ClientExt1 marina = new ClientExt1("Marina",14321,"marina.calder1@btinternet.com");
ArrayList<String> interests = new ArrayList<>();
interests.add("History");
interests.add("Music");
marina.setInterests(interests);
holidaySeller.getHolidayMatches(marina);
```

Client...

```
public class ClientExt1 {

private String name;
private int id;
private String email;
private HolidayExt1 holidayBooked;
private ArrayList<String> interests;

public ClientExt1(String name, int id, String email){
    this.name=name;
    this.id=id;
    this.email=email;


}

public void setInterests(ArrayList interests) {
    this.interests=interests;
}

public ArrayList<String> getInterests(){
    return interests;
```

Company class...

```
public class CompanyExt1 {
    protected ArrayList<StaffExt1> staffMembers;                  
    protected ArrayList<HolidayExt1> holidays;
    protected ArrayList<GuideExt1> holidayGuides;
    protected ArrayList<AdventureExt1> adventureHolidays;
    protected ArrayList<CultureExt1> cultureHolidays;
    private ArrayList<String> matchedHolidays;


    public ArrayList<String> findHolidayMatch(ClientExt1 client) {
        ArrayList interests = client.getInterests();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < holidays.size() && i< interests.size(); i++) {
            if (!Collections.disjoint(holidays.get(i).getAspects(), interests)) {
                matchedHolidays.add(holidays.get(i).getName());

            }
        }
        return matchedHolidays;
    }

    public void getHolidayMatches(ClientExt1 client){
        System.out.println(client.getName() + ", the holidays recommended to you based on your interests from this company are:" + findHolidayMatch(client));
    }
}
```

Comment: Add more of your code.

Comment: the debugger points towards the disjoint from Collections and at "  int c1size = c1.size();"

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `holidays` before you use it and `matchedHolidays` before you add values to it in `findHolidayMatch`

I would actually make matchedHolidays a local variable instead of a class member since it is only used in the scope of the findHolidayMatch method.